# Bloqueio de opções ao selecionar link em versão mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-hover

Olá gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de bloquear as opções de pagina quando segurar uma imagem na versão mobile, pois na versão web quando passo com o mouse  na imagem (hover) aparece a descrição, porém na versão mobile gostaria de quando segurar a imagem aparecer, segue o print das opções que desejo bloquear:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boa tarde,

pelo que entendi de sua pergunta, você precisa usar JS para customizar um evento, no caso, o evento "tap" mais longo.

Com jquery é bem prático "dar o trigger" nesse tipo de evento com o taphold, segue o link:
https://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/

Espero ter ajudado, abs